# Elasticsearch local instance

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if it is possible to distribute an elasticsearch instance packed within some sort of installer to run locally on a client's machine.
I know that elastic is ok to distribute, but I'm looking for some way to pack it up as a dependency in a larger project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess docker container is the best solution for your use case.
You can see this project :

https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

A requirement is the host/workstation targeted must have docker (+ optionnaly docker-composer) installed.

docker-compose allow to package a lot of container for example we could run a multi node cluster + kibana